# SQL Server 2008 : query to combine 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Table A which has columns `Product_id` & `Product_Price`. Table B has `Product_id` & `Product_desc`.

`Product_id` is of type `char(30)`. `product_Price` is `smallmoney` and `Product_desc` is `nvarchar (2000)`.

I am trying to produce a query which for each value of `Product_id`, we take `Product_desc` add TEXT followed by `product_price x 4`.

So I am thinking that I start with

```
UPDATE Table B 
SET Product_desc = Prouct_desc + TEXT
```

but when I run this SQL Server reports

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '180110"" ' to data type int.

My second problem is the correct syntax to append `product_price`.

I would be very grateful for some help with this please.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: A *query* retrieves data and usually starts with SELECT. UPDATE on the other hand changes data in the database. Which of these do you want?

Comment: Anyway I don't understand the error you are getting.  Prouct_desc is a string and TEXT is a string, too, I guess, so why does the DBMS say it fails to convert to INT? Why would it want to? Is there anything you didn't show us? Is `180110"" ` the content of TEXT?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE B 
    SET Product_desc = b.Product_desc + 'TEXT' + cast(a.product_price as varchar(255)) + ' x 4'
    FROM B JOIN
         A
         ON B.product_d = A.product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine the two columns like this :

```
SELECT [product_Desc] + ' TEXT ' + cast([product_Price] as varchar(200)) + ' x4'
FROM A
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,

```
UPDATE B 
SET Product_desc = b.Product_desc + 'TEXT' + cast(a.product_price as varchar(255)) + ' x 4'
FROM B 
JOIN A ON B.product_d = A.product_id;
```

That looks like what I am trying to do and I will give it a try.

Does the 'x4' actaully multiply by 4?

Comment: no it doesn't multiply by 4, this would cast(a.product_price*4 as varchar(255))